# Pod Install Failed

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native, realm

Downloaded the Realm Expo Template with React Native SDK (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@realm/expo-template-ts) and ran the ios command. It's now giving me this error:

⚠️  Something went wrong running `pod install` in the `ios` directory.
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=104.26.0.240:443 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Anyone know what's happening here ^ Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try reinstalling openssl use ```brew uninstall --force openssl``` and then ```brew install openssl```.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking questions, please provide as many details as possible so we get a clear picture of the environment. Please include the podfile in your question along with the version of Cocoapods and OS.